# JTable custom header renderer that looks like other headers with nimbus look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Any time I create a custom header renderer for a JTable it ends up not looking correct with the nimbus look and feel. The default table headers have a silvery gradient, custom renderers do not look that way. In the past I just avoided creating custom header renderers. Is it possible to copy the default look onto my new custom renderer? Basically I want to add a checkbox and have the area around it look like a normal column header, not just gray. I do know how to add the checkbox though and make it click-able. Thanks

Comment: Still interested in this question? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MyTableHeaderRendererPainter extends AbstractRegionPainter (javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter).

Look at how Nimbus styles their Painter https://github.com/xsstomy/javacode/blob/master/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/TableHeaderRendererPainter.java

Then you call on the component of your custom renderer

```
.setBackground(new MyTableHeaderRendererPainter());
```

Writing Painters is complicated. Unfortunately the Nimbus TableHeaderRendererPainter is not visible. Maybe you can use a Painter of a different lookandfeel to get an acceptable result.

Answer (score -1):

Use the default header renderer from your tableHeader:

`table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()`

Comment: That won't help with maintaining the right look for the header.  It'll draw differently on the screen.